# Can't get bookmark icon to show in Safari Mobile on iPad

Tags: ios, mobile, web, mobile-safari, mobile-website

I've been tasked with creating an icon that will represent a site when a user bookmarks it on an iOS device. Following a few tutorials on the subject, I added the following to the `<head>` section of my page.

```
<link href="http://mywebthingy/CDN/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<link href="http://mywebthingy/CDN/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" />
<link href="http://mywebthingy/CDN/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" />
<link href="http://mywebthingy/CDN/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" />
```

This works perfectly when adding a link to the page on the home screen. However, I can't seem to get it to work when adding it as a bookmark in Safari the way the Apple and Disney links are on the default install of the browser. I feel like there's something else that needs doing to get this to work properly but I can't find anything on the web.

Comment: It started showing up for Safari bookmarks after being added to the favorites for a day or two. I don't know what it was that made it start working but it seems to have a delay.